# I want the page to reload and run a function if the url does not contain a word

Tags: javascript, function, api, url

I want the page to reload and run a function if the url does not contain the word "location". As it is, the page does not run the window.location.replace part of the code, and I am getting jsonData undefined console errors. Any help would be great!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (document.location.href.indexOf('location') === -1) {
        fetch('https://ipapi.co/json/')
            .then(function (response) {
                response.json().then(jsonData => {
                    console.log(jsonData);
                    var city = jsonData.city;
                    window.location.replace("https://preapproval.mortgagestack.ca/?location=" + city);
                });
            })
    });
```

Comment: Running this code only gives me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'`

Comment: When I fix the brackets the code works as expected.

Comment: Same here, I fixed the missing bracket syntax error and the code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seem be fine, may be you forgot the } so it throw the error. You can try with the code bellow

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (document.location.href.indexOf('location') === -1) {
      fetch('https://ipapi.co/json/')
          .then(function (response) {
              response.json().then(jsonData => {
                  console.log(jsonData);
                  var city = jsonData.city;
                  window.location.replace("https://preapproval.mortgagestack.ca/?location=" + city);
              });
          })
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

@Kyle White, I put together a quick solution for this. I haven't tested it, but it should run (fingers crossed). Try it out:

```js
var loc = window.location.href;
var keyword = ""; //word you are looking for
var repw = "": //word you want to replace keyword with
if (loc.includes(keyword)){
     //do something if it does have the keyword
}else{
     //if it doesn't include 
     var rep = loc.replace(keyword, repw);
     window.open(rep, '_self');
}
```

To learn more, visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace to learn about the JS .includes() method, or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace to learn about the js .replace() function. For the window.open() syntax, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open.

Enjoy!

Comment: This won't solve OP's problem, because you stripped off all the `fetch` part. Actually, OP's code works, it's just a missing `}`. So your solution doesn't bring much, you even removed  the API call. But +1 for effort

Comment: @JeremyThille, this was on purpose. I was not fixing the users code, just explaining some useful js methods. "give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime." I'm happy you found his mistake though!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, I just rewrote it with `async/await`.

```js
(async() => {
  if (document.location.href.includes('location')) return;
  const response = await fetch('https://ipapi.co/json/');
  const jsonData = await response.json();
  console.log("jsonData = ", jsonData);
  const city = jsonData.city;
  window.location.replace("https://preapproval.mortgagestack.ca/?location=" + city);
})()
```

Comment: I'd remove the doc.ready wrapper; the only criterion is the URL so we don't need to wait for the page to load. Next I'd use URLSearchParams, and use a relative URL. Otherwise this is what I have and what works fine.

Comment: Ah, that's right we don't need to wait for doc.ready, good point

Comment: You still need an async wrapper function though ;)

Comment: Ah, and `return` needs to be inside a function now too :o)

Comment: There, all fixed!